# Display all categories but one in expression engine

Tags: expressionengine

My code is below I want to display all my categories except one that I want to link directly too. category_id_not doesn't seem to work.

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="4" style="linear" show_empty="yes" category_id_not="42"}
<option value="/events/category/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</option>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="4" style="linear" show_empty="yes" show="not 42"} 
    <option value="/events/category/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</option> 
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

`category_id_not` is not a valid parameter, nor is `category_id` (although that would be consistent and logical) you should use `show="not 42"` instead.

Full docs [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/categories.html#id23).